# Security rules at Firestore in Map within another Map

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm making the security rules for Firebase Firestore, but I can't reference the map inside another map, as shown in the image below. I need to reference the type and whether it is active.

Document with Map inside another Map:

[image]

I tried to use the following command:

`get (/databases/$(database)/documents/after_sales/{after_salesUID}/users_type).data.type in ['admin', 'approver'] &&`

`get (/databases/$(database)/documents/after_sales/{after_salesUID} /users_type.data.active == true;`

When trying to test access to the document, I receive the following error message "Error while running the simulation: An unknown error has occurred".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure of your complete database structure but I created a collection named 'companies' and a document in it.

[image]

These rules worked for me:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /companies/{companyID} {
      allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/$(companyID)).data.user_types[request.auth.uid].admin == true;
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure which location you are trying to access in your db but that's how you can read values in nested maps. Apparently it's `after_sales` ID in your case that I made user UID in my test.

Comment: Excellent! I managed to access the information! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sadly this is not a complete solution as currently my keys are random as per my design and this solution will not work. As assumption is that you know keys beforehand

Comment: @AndroidEngineX if your use case if different that this question then you should be posting a new question. Also it might be a better choice to not use dynamic keys otherwise you might have issues with indexes later.